# using ng-repeat for a specific slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I can't make this slider work, taking data from the controller.

This example works fine:

```
<div class="w-slider-mask"  >                 
    <div class="w-slide slide"></div>
    <div class="w-slide slide bg2"></div>
    <div class="w-slide slide bg3"></div>                 
</div>
```

How to use `ng-repeat` in this case?

Live demo : http://visitalhoceima.aandh-studio.com/demo2/index2.html#